# Casting result of an F function to an int

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a simple Django application were I try to aggregate multiple values into an annotation for easier processing on the client side.

Basically, I need to sum the values of multiple columns into one.

For this I'm trying to use `annotate` with `F` functions:

```
qs = TimeReport.objects \
         .filter(year=year, term=term) \
         .annotate(
              created_by_first_name=F('created_by__first_name'),
              created_by_last_name=F('created_by__last_name'),
              total_hours = F('master_thesis_supervision_hours')
                            + F('semester_project_supervision_hours')
                            + F('other_job_hours')
                            + F('MAN_hours')
                            + F('exam_proctoring_and_grading_hours')
                            + F('class_teaching_exam_hours')
                            + F('class_teaching_practical_work_hours')
                            + F('class_teaching_preparation_hours')
                            + F('class_teaching_teaching_hours'),
                            ) \
                .all().values()
```

Suprisingly, when I inspect the content of the calculated field, it does not contain anything:

```
list(qs)[0]['total_hours']
None
```

Trying to cast the result of the `F` function does not either:

```
...
  total_hours = int(F('master_thesis_supervision_hours'))
                +int(F('semester_project_supervision_hours'))
                + ...
```

I also tried to update the `models.py` to add a property:

```
@property
def total_hours(self):
    return self.master_thesis_supervision_hours + self.class_teaching_total_hours + self.semester_project_supervision_hours + self.other_job_hours + self.MAN_hours + self.exam_proctoring_and_grading_hours
```

and update the `views.py` accordingly:

```
qs = TimeReport.objects \
        .filter(year=year, term=term) \
        .annotate(
            created_by_first_name=F('created_by__first_name'),
            created_by_last_name=F('created_by__last_name'),
            total_hours = F('total_hours'),
            ) \
        .all().values()
```

But I get the following error:

> django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'total_hours' into field.

What would be the correct way to do this?

Comment: Where is this `F()` method coming from? Where is the definition of it.

Comment: @TinNguyen it is django built-in function https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#using-f-with-annotations

Comment: I think the problem is that you're summing up `F`s using `+`, you need to use `Sum` function or `ExpressionWrapper` with `output_field=FloatField()` or `output_field=IntegerField()`

Comment: @Sajad: using the ExpressionWrapper does not help. I will also try with the Sum function

Comment: @Sajad: Nope, the `sum()` does not help.

Comment: I use this in my current project and it works properly, see if it helps `.annotate(
  post_strength=ExpressionWrapper(ExpressionWrapper(F('related_proposal_count') + 
                                                    F('base_comments_count') + 
                                                    F('post_likes_count') + 
                                                    F('views_count'), output_field=FloatField()) +
                                  F('categories_relevancy_term')
                                  , output_field=FloatField()),
 )`

Comment: @Sajad I have *almost* the same thing. Why are you using `ExpressionWrapper` twice?

Comment: honestly it's a very old code, I think `F('categories_relevancy_term')` was sum of some other `F`s itself and I've been getting some errors!